# How to populate 2 tables during registration in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to give user free deposit after registration.therefore  i want to fill "deposit" table along with "users" table. i have tried below but i am getting error.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $basic = BasicSetting::first();
        $status = $basic->verify_status == 1 ? '0' : '1';
        $image25 = 'user-default.png';
        if ($basic->reference_id == $data['reference']){
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],

                'under_reference' => $data['reference'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                'verifyToken' => Str::random(40),
                'reference' => Str::random(12),
                'status' => $status,
                'image' => $image25
            ]);
            $Deposit = Deposit::create([
                'deposit_number' => date('ymd').Str::random(6).rand(11,99),
              'plan_id' => $data['planid'],
              'percent' => $data['percent'],
              'time' => $data['time'],
              'compound_id' => $data['comp'],
              'status' = $status
]);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what is your problem?? show us your db schema of this two table

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'

Comment: Make sure all key are exists in `$data` array e.g `time, comp` etc.

Comment: Use `status => $status` instead of `status = $status` in `Deposit` model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
'status' = $status
```

should be

```
'status' => $status
```

At

```
$Deposit = Deposit::create([
    'deposit_number' => date('ymd').Str::random(6).rand(11,99),
    'plan_id' => $data['planid'],
    'percent' => $data['percent'],
    'time' => $data['time'],
    'compound_id' => $data['comp'],
    'status' = $status     // <------------
]);
```

By the way, one best practice here is to use a **transaction**, because, if there is any error it will rollback both inserts.
So, your code could be:

```
if ($basic->reference_id == $data['reference']){
    \DB::transaction(function() use($data) {
        $basic = BasicSetting::first();
        $status = $basic->verify_status == 1 ? '0' : '1';
        $image25 = 'user-default.png';
        $user = User::create([ .... ]);
        $Deposit = Deposit::create([...]);
    });
}
```